# chainradar.com question

Tags: block-explorer

On the Monero page for chainradar there is an Amount field with a value that is different from the amount that I used for my transaction. What does this Amount value signify? Better yet, is there an FAQ that explains the values on this page?

The transaction ID in question is:

b9380726c4f8cc2e73dacfbbfb74c81bb998ca3f9dddc4f48d97f416a8d98e6f

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you spent less than 0.6 XMR in this transaction.  You must have received a 0.6 XMR denomination in the past, which remained an unspent output in your wallet until now.  That output was used as the input for the current transaction.  It was mixed with 8 other unspent outputs, so no one but you knows which was sent by you.

Note the output denominations of the transaction (.008, .03, .06, .2, .3).  The receiver in your transaction will be receiving some of those.  You'll receive at least one of those as well, since you'll receive change from paying with a larger denomination than you actually sent to the recipient.

Answer (score 1):

The amount field is the sum of outputs. It contains your money sent to someone (or what you received), a change returned to a sender (if any).

To check exactly what money you received or you sent to someone, better to use other explorer. e.g., http://blox.supportxmr.com/tx/b9380726c4f8cc2e73dacfbbfb74c81bb998ca3f9dddc4f48d97f416a8d98e6f